# Move to new row every 4th column

Tags: excel, vba

I got data that is stored in one row of columns in an excel sheet.
Is there a way to move data to next row every 4th column? Is there a built in function for this?
For example:

Data:

```
Actinium | Ac | 89 | 227.0278* | Aluminum | Al | 13 | 26,981539 ...
```

Output:

```
Actinium |Ac | 89 | 227.0278*
Aluminum |Al | 13 | 26,981539
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a macro:

```
Sub dela_igen()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, cur_column As Integer

cur_column = 1
For i = 1 To 100
    For j = 1 To 4
        Cells(i, j).Value = Cells(1, cur_column).Value
        cur_column = cur_column + 1
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Worked like a charm!

Comment: That works but the first row still has all the data in it that you have copied down onto the rows...